# Negative revision when checking HG repository

Tags: mercurial

I'm getting errors when pushing and pulling from a repo on a server. We have a repository (a folder) on a LAN-server which we push our commits to. This worked from the beginning but now it seems to not find the changesets on the server anymore, so tortoisehg ends up by trying to push all the revisions it locally has, to the server.
Also, when I view the repository on the LAN-server in HG workbench, it doesn't show any revision, the only one I can see is a revision -1?
So my question is, what have could gone wrong? And is there a way to fix this? I already replaced the repository on the server with my local one, and that went well for a few days until it happened again.

Answer (score 0):

What Mercurial version are you using?
It's possible that you have been impacted by the bug fixed in [Mercurial 3.3.2](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew) (released yesterday).

The solution in that case is to upgrade to Mercurial 3.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Revision -1 is what mercurial shows on an empty repository right after a `hg init` without any commit whatsoever.

If your LAN server exports the repository over a windows network share, indeed it might have been a serious bug fixed in Mercurial 3.3.2 (see https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4546 - maybe you can reproduce that with a new test repo. Upgrade, if that's the case for you)